# How to use/include qml module in CMake desktop application

Tags: qt, qml

I’m relatively new to Qt and QtQick in particular and am trying to render a PDF file in my qml application (OS: Win10, platform: Desktop). To achieve this I built QtPdf following the instructions in the Qt Wiki.

My project structure is as follows:

```
|myProject
   |-- qml  
      |-- QtQuick  
         |-- Pdf  
             qmldir  
             plugins.qmltypes  
             pdfplugin.dll  
             [...] 
   main.cpp
   main.qml
   someComponent.qml
   [...]
```

I’m building with CMake and added the import path like it is described here:

```
set(QML_IMPORT_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/qml ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/imports CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
```

And I imported the module in my qml files using

```
import QtQuick.Pdf 5.15
```

Sadly I get a “QML module not found” exception. Obviously I’m missing something important and would be grateful if someone could point me to it.
If something is unclear or you need more information or code snippets from any files, I'm happy to provide the information needed.

Comment: You can try `QML2_IMPORT_PATH`, but actually I think you should set the path runtime with `QQmlEngine::addImportPath`

Comment: The best way it to create a new project using QtCreator and select CMake as a build tool from the wizard. That will build all the files/dependencies you need.